# Angularfire $add().then() returns oddly formated object

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using AngularJS and Firebase and AngularFire.

The following code is giving me trouble:

```
images.$add(imageUpload).then(function(ref) {
            console.log(ref);
        });
```

I've used similar code elsewhere, which works just fine, but here I get objects that look like this returned:

```
H {n: be, path: J, Ca: undefined, da: undefined, va: undefined…}
Aa: undefined
Ca: undefined
Ra: undefined
da: undefined
n: be
path: J
va: undefined
__proto__: c
```

I've tried messing around to discover what I'm doing wrong, but with no luck. I'm assuming I'm doing something relatively simple wrong?

I've fiddled around with it and discovered that they key of the newly created data, which is what I'm looking for, is actually stored under path/m. So it seems like the data returned is simply just being formatted oddly?

By using:

```
console.log(ref.path.m[1]);
```

I can get what I would have expected to find calling

```
console.log(ref.name);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I expect that what you're getting into `then` is a Firebase DataSnapshot (documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/index.html). You can get the value, by doing `ref.val()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name is a function and not a key in the data. So to get the id back you must call:

```
console.log(ref.name());
```

rather than:

```
console.log(ref.name);
```

Comment: Excellent.. Knew it was something stupid I was doing wrong! Thanks